# CP2102 usb to serial error

Tags: ubuntu, usb, serial-port

I'm trying to flash the nodemcu fw for the esp8266 using a usb to serial adapter, it come mounted on `/dev/ttyUSB0` but it can't communicate with the module. All the connection are ok, and I've also tried with a Windows PC, so the problem is software side. This is the dmesg output:

```
[ 3144.796181] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 70 using uhci_hcd
[ 3144.957166] usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60
[ 3144.957174] usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1,Product=2,SerialNumber=3
[ 3144.957180] usb 5-1: Product: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[ 3144.957184] usb 5-1: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[ 3144.957188] usb 5-1: SerialNumber: 0001
[ 3144.962334] cp210x 5-1:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[ 3144.964477] usb 5-1: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

and this what appear when I try to upload the code:

```
python luatool.py -p /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 9600 -f webserver.lua -t webserver.lua

s->file.open("webserver.lua", "w")Traceback (most recent call last):
File "luatool.py", line 118, in <module>
writeln("file.open(\""+args.dest+"\", \"w\")\r")
File "luatool.py", line 41, in writeln
raise Exception('No proper answer from MCU')
Exception: No proper answer from MCU
```

P.S. I am running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you're trying to flash the NodeMCU firmware, but your example line shows you trying to upload a Lua source file.  If you've already flashed the firmware, my best suggestion would be to try to install Minicom (sudo apt-get install minicom) and using that to confirm your connection in Ubuntu.  Something like "sudo minicom -b 9600 -D /dev/ttyUSB0" should work.

If you haven't flashed the firmware yet, you'll need to do that first.  Connect GPIO0 to ground to put the ESP8266 into update mode.  Then use [esptool](https://github.com/themadinventor/esptool) to flash.  The command should be something along the lines of "esptool.py -p /dev/ttyUSB0 write_flash [nodemcu firmware file]".  The firmware files are available from the NodeMCU github.